# Torch CAddTable.output is wrong: holds only 0 and 1 values

Tags: lua, conv-neural-network, torch, resnet

I would like to obtain the activations at each layer on a pre-trained ResNet after a forward pass. For most layers, I can just use the Module's output parameter to query the activation, however for CAddTable, the output parameter only contains 0 or 1 values, corresponding to the sign of the true output during the forward pass. The ReLU unit following the CAddTable holds non-integer values, suggesting that during forward pass, the CAddTable returned the correct values.

For example, for a single feature map, I have 2 inputs to the CAddTable:

Input 1:

```
(1,1,.,.) = 
 -0.4010 -0.4658 -0.2517 -0.2863 -0.2731 -0.3428 -0.2685
 -1.1177 -1.3387 -0.7699 -0.5595 -0.5505 -0.7473 -0.6121
 -1.7965 -1.8100 -0.7766 -0.2923 -0.2297 -0.8788 -0.9094
 -1.5759 -0.7506  0.5790  0.8329  0.0072 -1.5523 -1.5252
  0.1142  1.1772  1.6391  1.2629 -0.2074 -2.1833 -1.9419
  0.9352  1.8757  1.5200  0.8178 -0.5817 -2.1865 -1.7899
  1.1880  2.0332  1.3987  0.3307 -1.0040 -2.0327 -1.5910
[torch.CudaTensor of size 1x1x7x7]
```

Input 2:

```
(1,1,.,.) = 
  0.0000  0.0000  0.1688  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
  1.1719  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
  2.3147  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.6100
  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
  1.0300  0.4141  1.2499  0.1507  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
  3.0425  1.5787  0.5076  0.7407  0.8804  0.0000  0.0000
[torch.CudaTensor of size 1x1x7x7]
```

CAddTable output (I expect this to be the sum of inputs, but it's actually kind of a unit-step function of the sum)

```
(1,1,.,.) = 
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  0  1  1  1  0  0
  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
[torch.CudaTensor of size 1x1x7x7]
```

Output from the ReLU unit following CAddTable

```
(1,1,.,.) = 
  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
  0.7388  0.0000  0.5790  0.8329  0.0072  0.0000  0.0000
  0.1142  1.1772  1.6391  1.2629  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
  1.9651  2.2899  2.7700  0.9686  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
  4.2305  3.6119  1.9063  1.0714  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
[torch.CudaTensor of size 1x1x7x7]
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: I stumbled upon the same problem and I just wonder, have you got any solution for this?